# r - Why does rlm (MASS package) return a model without intercept?

Tags: r, regression

Test code:

```
rlm(x=runif(100, 100, 200), y=runif(100, 10000, 10002))
lm(runif(100, 10000, 10002)~runif(100, 100, 200))
```

Result of lm() is sensible:

```
Coefficients:
         (Intercept)  runif(100, 100, 200)  
           1.000e+04            -1.024e-03
```

However, rlm() provides a model without intercept

```
Call:
rlm(x = runif(100, 100, 200), y = runif(100, 10000, 10002))
Converged in 4 iterations

Coefficients:
runif(100, 100, 200) 
            62.01507
```

Package info:

```
packageVersion("MASS")
[1] ‘7.3.51.1’
```

Edit: Thanks to Sal Mangiafico, I found out that `rlm()` can only consider intercept if we use `~` syntax

```
Call: rlm(formula = runif(100, 10000, 10002) ~ runif(100, 100, 200))
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.94878 -0.49492 -0.01952  0.51689  1.02064 

Coefficients:
                     Value      Std. Error t value   
(Intercept)          10001.0276     0.3213 31128.1471
runif(100, 100, 200)    -0.0004     0.0021    -0.1837

Residual standard error: 0.7588 on 98 degrees of freedom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Note: There's a potential that there's a question about statistics here, but I think it comes down to a programming problem. ~ ssm]

If you use parallel syntax in the function calls, for this example there's little difference in the results.

```
set.seed(sum(utf8ToInt("SalWasHere")))

library(MASS)

x=runif(100, 100, 200)
y=runif(100, 10000, 10002)

plot(x,y)

summary(rlm(y ~ x))

   ### Coefficients:
   ###             Value      Std. Error t value   
   ### (Intercept) 10001.2272     0.3350 29851.0467
   ### x              -0.0018     0.0022    -0.8106

summary(lm(y ~ x))

   ### Coefficients:
   ###              Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
   ### (Intercept) 1.000e+04  2.914e-01 34319.556   <2e-16 ***
   ### x           4.925e-06  1.903e-03     0.003    0.998
```